# C# : Bluetooth GATT communication. GattCharacteristic.ValueChanged doesnt gets hit after sometime

Tags: c#, wpf, bluetooth

I am working on wpf application that uses GATT for bluetooth communication. I am using GattCharacteristic.ValueChanged to handle any value from device. It works for sometime and the event handler doesnt gets called after 1 minute. This problem observed in windows 8.1, but working in windows 10.

I am made GattCharacteristic member variable, so the GC doesnt collect the variable. Still the problem exists.

Can anyone tell me what could be the potential problem here?

```
private GattCharacteristic m_DataSenderCharacteristics;
foreach (var service in serviceInfo)
{
var uuid = MjGattDeviceService.UuidFromServiceInformation(service);
//Battery Service
if (uuid.ToString() == BatteryUUID)
{
    var bService = await GattDeviceService.FromIdAsync(service.Id);
    m_Device.batteryService = bService;
}
if (uuid.ToString() == CustomServiceUUID)
{
    m_Device.gattService = await GattDeviceService.FromIdAsync(service.Id);

    Guid controlGUID = new Guid(ControlUUID);
    var controlGattCharacteristics =      m_Device.gattService.GetCharacteristics(controlGUID);
    Byte[] bsdata = new Byte[] { 0x0b, 0x00, 0x02 };
    IBuffer buffUTF8 = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(bsdata);
    GattCommunicationStatus status = await controlGattCharacteristics[0].WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);

    if (status == GattCommunicationStatus.Unreachable)
    {
        m_Device.isConnected = false;
        nextPage = "Unreachable";
    }
    else if (status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
    {
        var ctrlStatus = await controlGattCharacteristics[0].WriteValueAsync(buffUTF8);
        Guid guuid1 = new Guid(DataSenderUUID);
        m_DataSenderCharacteristics = m_Device.gattService.GetCharacteristics(guuid1)[0];

        GattCommunicationStatus notifyStatus = await m_DataSenderCharacteristics.
            WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);                   

        //This event handler will be called for some 1 minute. After it falls dead
        m_DataSenderCharacteristics[0].ValueChanged += GestureValueChanged;
        if (notifyStatus == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
        {
            nextPage = "Connected";
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You can show some code that you use?

Comment: Hi.. Please check the code..

Comment: I am experiencing a similar issue. It happens to me anytime I perform an asynchronous request to my local SQLite db. Not sure if it is being GC or something with async requests. Did you ever find a solution?